# React Native Paper Dropdown opens menu on screen right and not aligned properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I am Using React Native Expo 4.4.4

[I am using the React native Paper DropDown Library from this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paper-dropdown)  : 
"react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.2"

I went to the readme section and copied the code given from Basic Example. But the menu is appearing somewhere on the screen as given below.

Is this the issue with the library or am I missing anything?

[image: Screen shot of DropDown menu]

Answer (score 0):

Your `View`'s style has the property `justifyContent : "center", alignItems: "center"` That is why you are getting this.

Give the `width: "100%"` to the `View` this will give you the desired result.

Comment: Tried this
No luck ever after that

Comment: Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/dropdown) out

Comment: Its crashing on ios and android.. Can you check once